# How to vertically center an absolute child relative to his parent and move it starting from that point?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a button with an icon as its child, overlaping its parent (the button) and being vertically centered relative to it.

Here is the result i want to obtain :
[image: wanted result]

The button is declared like this :

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-stage" >DIR <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down indicator" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
```

And the CSS to obtain what I currently have is this :

```
.btn-stage {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
    font-size: 19px;
    position: relative;
}

.indicator {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 32px;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(50%, 5%);
    left: 35%;
    color: #005bbb;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The problem with using transform is that depending on the size of the window the icon slides left or right and never ends up really in the middle:
[image: Too large exemple] & [image: Too small exemple]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_center-vertical.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To vertically center an element in absolute, you can do :

```css
.indicator {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

top + translateY() = vertically centering
left + translateX() = horizontally centering

To do what you really want, vertically center on parent bottom and not on parent center. You can do : `top 100%;` or `bottom: 0;`

Comment: I've added a margin-top:27px; to lower it in place just as in "wanted result" and it works great ! Thanks :)

Comment: To add a bit more explication, left and top move top-left corner of the tag and % depends on parent sizes. To re-center child element from its top left corner, we use translate -50% that depends of its own sizes and make its center to the parent center.

Comment: I reject the edit, because I answered to the title quesiton which is "vertically centered".

Comment: I have edit now with that you really want I think @Val_

Answer (score 0):

change

```
left: 35%;
transform: translate(50%, 5%);
```

to

```
transform: translate(-50%, 5%);
left: 50%;
```

Explainition: the percentage of the `left` property are relative to the width of the parent, and the `transform` percentage are relative to the element size itself.